# Angular router navigation inside NgRx effect

Tags: angular, ngrx, angular-router, ngrx-effects

Does the Angular router have any restrictions to be used inside an NgRx effect?

I just started learning NgRx and I have the following code:

```
@Effect() public authenticate$ = this.actions$
    .ofType(authenticationActions.AUTHENTICATE)
        .switchMap((action: AuthenticateAction) => this.authenticationService.authenticate(action.payload)
            .map((data: TokenData) => {
                const user: User = {
                    token: data.token,
                    username: 'dummy',
                };
                console.log(data);
                this.router.navigateByUrl('/');
                return new authenticationActions.AuthenticateSuccessAction(user);
            })
            .catch(error => { console.log(error); return Observable.throw(error); })
        );
```

The console logs the data variable and the `AuthenticateSuccessAction` action is being triggered, so the router line is being executed but the navigation doesn't happen.

Comment: This should work normally, maybe try a different URL to make sure that its not a bug before you're navigating to root? `this.router.navigateByUrl('/login')`; Ensure you're not using something like an AuthGuard that redirects you back to your login screen.

Comment: I already tried different urls and also disabled all guards and created a test button in the login page to use that same statement and it navigates. The problem is that statement inside the effect. This is very very strange

Comment: I have similar implementation as you and am able to route my app without problem. This is silly but, make sure you've injected the router in your constructor.

Comment: do the navigation within `tap` operator (in older versions of rxjs it was called `do`).

Answer (score 29, accepted):

```
@Effect() public authenticate$ = this.actions$.pipe(
    ofType(authenticationActions.AUTHENTICATE),
     map(action => action.payload),
    exhaustMap((auth: any) => 
      this.authenticationService.authenticate(auth)
        .map((data: TokenData) => {
            return user: User = {
                token: data.token,
                username: 'dummy',
            };
        }).catch(error => { console.log(error); return Observable.throw(error); 
       }).pipe(
          map(user =>new authenticationActions.AuthenticateSuccessAction(user))
        )
    );)

  @Effect({ dispatch: false })
   loginSuccess$ = this.actions$.pipe(
     ofType(authenticationActions.AuthenticateSuccessAction),
     tap(() => this.router.navigate(['/']))
   );
```

Use exhaustMap and when you dispatching 'AuthenticateSuccessAction' action, do another effect for redirecting.

Personally, I like to separate all the services from effects, then you can use catchError() operator after success login for dispatching another action in case of failure login.

hope this works.
PS: I did not verify this answer but logic is like this.

Comment: that dispatch: false is key ;-)

Comment: @Stuart Allen thx mate! I was wondering why effect kept looping

Comment: Interesting to see you dispatch a single action that goes both to the reducer and the next effect handler. I will see if this works but I hope it does.

Comment: From angular 11, @Effect() is deprecated ! You have to use creatEffect instead : see https://ngrx.io/guide/migration/v11 at the bottom of this page : you will find all explanation.

Answer (score 13):

There should be an approach allowing not to create separate effect for redirect, something like

```js
this.actions$.pipe(
  ofType(authenticationActions.AUTHENTICATE),
  switchMap(action =>
    this.authenticationService.authenticate(action.payload).pipe(
      map(data => new authenticationActions.successAction(data)),
      tap(() => this.router.navigate(['/'])),
      catchError(error => new authenticationActions.failAction(error))
    )
);
```

The thing is that `tap` will not be invoked if the service call failed, both `map` and `tap` will be skipped in favor of `catchError` if the failure case.

Comment: From angular 11, @Effect() is deprecated ! You have to use creatEffect instead : see https://ngrx.io/guide/migration/v11 at the bottom of this page : you will find all explanation.

Answer (score 5):

following the response of m.akbari, in the case they use the actions differently, the "dispatch : false" **goes to the last**.

the key is the "**dispatch : false**", if this is not indicated an infinite loop is generated

```
 loginNavigate$ = createEffect(
    () => this.actions$.pipe(
        ofType(usuariosActions.loginUsuarioSuccess),
        tap(() => {
            console.log('iniciando la navegacion');

            this.router.navigate(['/']);
        })
    ), { dispatch: false }
);
```

Answer (score 0):

When using `this.router.navigate()` in combination with `@ngrx/router-store` effects, there a few things to consider when handling navigation:

1. Use `mergeMap` instead of `tap` because `this.router.navigate()` returns a promise and tap doesn't allow asynchronous operations to be resolved or awaited.
2. `{ dispatch: false }` indicates that this effect does not dispatch any new action.
3. Use `catchError` to handle errors that may occur during navigating. If using `catchError` do not include `{ dispatch: false }` in the effect options since you will be dispatching an action to handle the error.

Example:

```js
navigateTo$ = createEffect(
  () => {
    return this.actions$.pipe(
      ofType(myActions.navigateTo),
      mergeMap(({ path }) => {
        return this.router.navigate([path]);
      })
    );
  },
  { dispatch: false }
);
```

To handle errors, we can modify the code as follows:

```js
navigateTo$ = createEffect(
  () => {
    //...
      catchError(error => of(myActions.doSomething())
    //...
  },
  // { dispatch: false }
);
```